# How to retrieve current user's Outlook email address with late binding?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, outlook-2010

I was trying to figure out how to use late binding in an excel module to retrieve the current user's email address for 'auto-emailing' upon execution of a macro.

I'll post the solution below. I am using Excel 2010 but it works on 2013 as well.

Answer (score 3):

```
Dim OL, olAllUsers, oExchUser, oentry, myitem As Object
Dim User As String

Set OL = CreateObject("outlook.application")
Set olAllUsers = OL.Session.AddressLists.Item("All Users").AddressEntries

User = OL.Session.CurrentUser.Name

Set oentry = olAllUsers.Item(User)

Set oExchUser = oentry.GetExchangeUser()

msgbox oExchUser.PrimarySmtpAddress
```

Comment: You should add `as object` after each variable in the first declaration

Comment: thanks for the tip. out of curiosity, what advantage or benefit does that provides versus how i did it?

Comment: If you `dim a, b, c as x` only `c` is of type `x`, `a` and `b` are variants with no type.  It looks like a shorthand to set the types of all 3 but really isn't.

Comment: Works for me, just needed to adjust the address list name. Thanks.